# How do you directly call a native function exported from a DLL?

Tags: c#

How do you directly call a native function exported from a DLL? Can someone just give me a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a quick example of the `DllImport` attribute in action:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class C
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int MessageBoxA(int h, string m, string c, int type);
    public static int Main()
    {
        return MessageBoxA(0, "Hello World!", "Caption", 0);
    }
}
```

This example shows the minimum requirements for declaring a C# method that is implemented in a native DLL. The method `C.MessageBoxA()` is declared with the static and external modifiers, and has the `DllImport` attribute, which tells the compiler that the implementation comes from the *user32.dll*, using the default name of *MessageBoxA*.

Refer [this link](http://www.techpreparation.com/computer-interview-questions/c-sharp-interview-questions-answers2.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This is [Microsoft example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

If you need to generate C# DLLImport declarations from a native dll, watch this post: [Generate C# DLLImport declarations from a native dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771648/generate-c-sharp-dllimport-declarations-from-a-native-dll)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly you want ... I have something like this in my code but this uses the Win32 API dll's

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

then just call

```
 GetForegroundWindow()
```

as if defined inside the class